# Push after filter-branch --index-filter?

Tags: git

I've just run:

```
git filter-branch --indexfilter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file>' --tag-name-filter cat -- --all HEAD
```

However when I run

```
git push origin master --force
```

It's saying "Everything up-to-date".

What am I doing wrong here or have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that your filter-branch hasn't modified anything, so there's nothing new to push.

Comment: But I can see that the file is no longer in my repository. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that `origin/master` and `master` point to different commits (check the SHA1, or see it your favorite graphical Git GUI)?

Comment: No commit was made, I was running filter branch --index-filter which re-writes the history. No new commits were made. Would this mean I screwed up my filter-branch?

Comment: No commits were made, sure, but are the commits different (SHA1) from origin?

Comment: Looks like the original command messed up for some reason. I re-cloned and re-did the process and it has all worked fine now. Sorry and thanks!